# Clear div content

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("refresh.php", function(result) {
            $('#response').empty()
            .hide()
            .html(result)
            $("#response").append(result)
            .fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

actually my script hits refresh.php every 5seconds in **refresh.php** i fetch data from mysql db and create a template like:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Name<td><td>$fetch['name']</td></tr>
</table>
```

I checked on firebug my refresh.php send response only once after 5seconds but on all browsers it shows the result two times like:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Name<td><td>$fetch['name']</td></tr>
    </table>
<table>
    <tr><td>Name<td><td>$fetch['name']</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shows the result twice because you're putting it there twice: First using [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html), then using [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append):

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("refresh.php", function(result) {
            $('#response').empty()
            .hide()
            .html(result)                 // <==== Here
            $("#response").append(result) // <==== And here
            .fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

`html` replaces the content of the element with the markup (or element[s]) you supply (there's no need for `empty` prior to using it). `append` *appends* the markup (or element[s]) you supply to the element.

You want one or the other. I'd go with `html`:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("refresh.php", function(result) {
            $('#response')
                .hide()
                .html(result)
                .fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following

```
$.get("refresh.php", function(result) {

    $("#response").html(result);
});
```